# Deleting comment violating SE policies

Tags: support

This concerns the comments following [my response to question *Does Hamas have any leverage against Israel (other than the hostages)?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82921/38304) I flagged a comment that referred to some of my assertion as *ludicrous*, and moderators removed the comment and the subsequent discussion. There is however another comment which makes the same point, but in a stronger language, which the moderators have probably simply missed:

> Downvoted for **the idiotic rants** about "over-mediatization" - not only a value judgement on how much coverage you think an ongoing massacre should attract, but qualified without any evidence whatsoever for "hardly made a topic". You must have a good memory if you can remember off the top of your head each news story that broke on each of those conflicts. Not to mention this current "war" really isn't one so much as it is a massacre borne out of revenge, which the casualty figures cited are evidence of.

(emphasis is mine)

Just wanted to attract attention of the moderators. Please abstain of using the Meta for discussing validity of either the answer or the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cleaned up a ton of comments on that post 22 hour ago. That comment was posted 18 hours ago, so it wasn't there yet when I did it. Now I deleted that comment as well.

Please note that people post a whole lot of comments right now, especially on the topics concerning the Israel/Hamas conflict. It's simply impossible for us moderators to read and evaluate every single one of them, so we have to rely on your [flags](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that you are likely overloaded with requests. I just thought that the moderator didn't pay attention to multiple flags, since they were in the same thread and thus possibly referred to the debate runaway between the same people.